# Read an Excel (xlsx) file on OneDrive using C# & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, excel, model-view-controller, onedrive, file-read

I have a OneDrive shared link for an excel file with some data. And I need to read this excel file through my C# ASP.NET MVC web application without downloading it to local PC. But I'm new to this 'OneDrive API'. So I have a serious challenge with this. I'm familiar with local file read as in,

EX:

```
var package = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(PATH));
```

I'd really appreciate if anyone can guide me or provide a sample code to do this. I just need to access the `ExcelPackage` of the `.xlsx` file. Thank you in advance.

PS : I have tried some options like 'WebRequest', 'Webclient', etc. :(

Comment: are you sure you googled "OneDrive API read .NET" and check SO already?

Comment: Yes. I've already tried few of them. But I just cannot get the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like [HttpClient.GetStreamAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstreamasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) to open a download stream for the remote file and then pass the returned `Stream` to the `ExcelPackage` constructor (documentation states it has a constructor that accepts an instance of a `Stream`).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have tried it. But unfortunately couldn't accomplish the task. However thank you so much for helping out. Thumbs up.